# Disable support for iPad Pro in a Universal app using a Launch Screen

Tags: ios, ipad, launch-screen

My iOS app has a minimum target of iOS 8, is Universal, and uses a Launch Screen XIB.

Is there a way to disable support for iPad Pro, so that it runs the standard iPad resolution up-scaled?

Comment: Creating the launch screen causes the iPadPro to operate in native iPadPro (full) resolution mode. Deleting it should enable upscale mode. My understanding is that if you create a launch image (rather than a launch screen) for the iPadPro you will also enter full resolution mode. I'm not sure you can release an app that does not support native iPadPro resolution (by not creating a launch screen or an image).

Answer (score 1):

Change the project to use Launch Images (asset catalog) instead of a Launch Screen (storyboard).